# How to reference a class blueprint as an argument in a function while specifying the class' arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing

The following is the set-up.

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def some_func1(self, paramA):
        some_input = paramA
        print(some_input)

class SomeOtherClass():
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

obj = SomeClass()

# Scenario #1
some_var = obj.some_func1(paramA=SomeOtherClass)
# <class '__main__.SomeOtherClass'>

# Scenario #2
some_other_var = obj.some_func1(paramA=SomeOtherClass(param1='val1', param2='val2'))
# <__main__.SomeOtherClass object at 0x000002576E88FD60>
```

The problem is in my actual example, none of these two configurations works. In Scenario #1, `SomeOtherClass` is referenced for the `some_func1`'s `paramA` argument. In Scenario #2, the required arguments to instantiate `SomeOtherClass` were specified, but the problem is I do NOT want to instantiate it at the argument level.

How can I reference (and not instantiate) the `SomeOtherClass` with specified parameter values, as a value of a function's argument?

Comment: What do you want it to actually do?  I.e. once you've got the class and the parameters, what do you want to do with them, if not actually instantiate the object?

Comment: I just want the reference of `SomeOtherClass` with specified parameter values while being referenced as a function argument. I want to instantiate it within `some_func1` later on.

Comment: Maybe just pass in a thunk (a `lambda` expression) that creates the object, then?  I'll write an answer demonstrating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to delay evaluation of something (including object instantiation) is to wrap it in a `lambda`:

```
class SomeClass():
    def some_func1(self, thunk):
        """thunk: a callable that takes no args and constructs an object."""
        print(thunk)
        obj = thunk()  # this actually instantiates the object
        print(obj)


class SomeOtherClass():
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

obj = SomeClass()

some_var = obj.some_func1(lambda: SomeOtherClass('val1', 'val2'))
```

If you needed the class and the params as distinct args for some other purpose, you could do:

```
def some_func1(self, obj_class, *params):
    print(obj_class, params)
    obj = obj_class(*params)
    print(obj)

some_func1(SomeOtherClass, 'val1', 'val2')
```